# Altering a Partitioned Table

Tags: mysql, database-performance, partition, database-partitioning

I can't find info online about this.

What are the best way to alter a table that is already partitioned?

should I just use the normal

```
UPDATE `table` MODIFY COLUMN `column_name` TINYINT(1) DEFAULT 1 NOT NULL;
```

and lock the table for several minutes

or should I run that command partition by partition?

```
UPDATE `table` PARTITION (p0) MODIFY COLUMN `column_name` TINYINT(1) DEFAULT 1 NOT NULL;
```

What are your recommendations?
What happens if not all partitions are exactly equal? is that even possible?

This is the create statement:

```
CREATE TABLE `redirects` (
   `emailhash` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
   `f_email_log` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
   `linknum` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '1',
   `redirect` varchar(500) NOT NULL,
   `clicked` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
   `clicktime` datetime NOT NULL DEFAULT '0000-00-00 00:00:00',
   PRIMARY KEY (`emailhash`),
   KEY `f_email_log` (`f_email_log`)
 ) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8
 /*!50100 PARTITION BY KEY (emailhash)
 PARTITIONS 16 */
```

The table has around 40 million records.

I want to reduce the size of some fields like INT to TINYINT since those values are mostly 1-30 or 0/1, as well as the varchar lengths since I've found that those number are too large and can be reduced.

Answer (score 1):

Altering a partitioned table requires altering each partition one at a time.  Meanwhile, the entire table needs to be locked, otherwise, reads/writes will stumble over a half-finished Alter.

Please provide `SHOW CREATE TABLE`, the number of partitions, the rationale for partitioning at all, and indicate which column needs changing.  We may be able to suggest a work-around.

**More**

400M rows would be about 12GB for that schema?
4GB buffer_pool (which could be raised to 11G for that much RAM)
md5 for key
--> 67% of inserts and selects will not find the desired block in RAM (cache), so would have to hit the disk.  This leads to sluggish performance.  It will only get worse as the table grows.  And it won't matter whether it is partitioned or not.  (No I cannot explain the difference you report.)

See [*here*](http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/uuid) for more discussion, but no good solution for your use case.

Shrinking the datatypes (4-byte `INT` --> 1-byte `TINYINT UNSIGNED`, etc) will help some.  `UNHEX(md5)` would let you put the hash in 16 bytes: `BINARY(16)`, thereby saving something like 18 bytes over what you have now.  Shrinking the max on `VARCHAR` has little or no effect.  Ditto for `CHARACTER SET`.

The query would need `where emailhash=UNHEX('abcdef1234567890')`

**ALTER**

Back to the original question of how to do the ALTER "fast".  Unless you *already* have replication set up, you are mostly out of luck.  The partitions must always have the same schema, so your idea about altering them one-by-one is not possible.

But... check `pt-online-schema-change` and `gh-ost` to see if they will work with partitioned tables.

Comment: I've added the code to the original question. Any idea?

Comment: `PARTITION BY KEY(the-primary-key)` is useless for performance.  What where you hoping to gain by partitioning?  Also, there is about 100MB of overhead for a 16-partition table.

Comment: Assuming "hash" is very random, you are stuck with jumping around the table all the time.  I assume you do not have enough RAM to cache the entire table?  Hence performance will suffer.

Comment: If the "hash" is hex or ascii, don't use utf8 for that column.

Comment: Before the partition, the table was very slow even in a single select by primary key, after the partition, that was no longer a problem. But strange thing is that only 8 of 16 partitions has data... only p0,p2,p4, etc. the other 8 are empty.

Comment: What do you recommend instead of utf8?

Comment: `CHARACTER SET ASCII`

Comment: How is the hash computed?  Let's see an example of the "very slow" query.  Was `emailhash` the `PRIMARY KEY` then?

Comment: `select redirect from email_redirects where emailhash='abcdef1234567890'`
The hash is a random md5

Comment: How much RAM?  What was the value of `innodb_buffer_pool_size`?

Comment: `16gb ram` / `innodb_buffer_pool_size: 4194304000`